# Remote deploy WSP Files to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: development

I create some WSP Files on a build server every night and would like to automatically deploy them to a QA Environment.

In SharePoint 2007, there was no way to remote deploy WSP Files except for ugly psexec-workarounds.

Has this improved with SharePoint 2010? Can I utilize the PowerShell stuff somehow?

My build server is not Part of the SharePoint farm. It doesn't even run the same SharePoint version (It runs a standalone Foundation, whereas the real farm runs Standard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in to SP2010 to provide for this, but the remoting story in PowerShell is much better than psexec.

Zach Rosenfield has a blog post about installing SharePoint remotely that should help you get started.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step/

Comment: cood answer. You should look around more often Paul :-)

Comment: "cood" = a combination of cool and good? It is always a good idea to post the most useful parts of blog posts here, and also link to the source. That link is dead.